# Differentiability of a function $f:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

I want to prove that the funktion

$f:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R,\hspace{0.5cm} f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
    (x^2+y^2)\sin\big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\big),& \text{if } (x,y)\neq (0,0)\\
    0,& \text{if } (x,y)=(0,0)              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

I already know that the partial derivatives are not continuous so unfortunately I have to show this by using the definition. Its clear that I only have to show differentiability in $(0,0)$. So, I have to write down

$f(h)-f((0,0))=Ah+r(h)$ where $r(h)$ tends faster to zero as $h$ for $h\rightarrow 0$($h\in \mathbb R^2).$

I have then (let $h=(h',h'')$)

$((h')^2+(h'')^2)\sin\big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{(h')^2+(h'')^2}}\big)=...$

and I dont know what belongs to the RHS.

Edit: I just find out that $A=0$ (the zero matrix) works. Is this correct? (Because if the LHS=r(h) then the conditions are met).

Comment: What do you want to show?  Continuity?

Comment: You're right: $\;f(x,y)-f(0,0)=o\bigl(\lVert (x,y\rVert\bigr)$ (for the *Euclidean norm*, hence for all).

Comment: @Bernard Alright, thanks :)

Comment: Note that this is just a two dimensional radial definition using $t^2 \sin(1/t)$, which is differentiable at $t=0$ (that is, replace $t=|(x,y)|$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can prove that for a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lVert f(\mathbf{x}) \rVert \leq \lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert^2$, for $\mathbf{x}$ in some open set containing $\mathbf{0}$ , $f$ is differentiable at $\mathbf{0}$ and $\mathbb{D}f(\mathbf{0})=\mathbf{0}$.

Then considering that $r^2\leq r, 0\leq r\leq 1$, the result follows for the function in question.